# Switch directly to the Game Center app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, game-center

I have a method that checks if the player is signed in to Game Center or not. If not I would like to bring up an alert view with a button that directly takes them to the Game Center app to sign in. Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just open gamecenter URL on button tap.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"gamecenter:"]];
```

Also put handle url in app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than forcing the user to switch between applications, Apple recommends that you show the Game Centre UI within your own application. This involves setting the `authenticateHandler` property or calling `authenticateWithCompletionHandler` on the `GKLocalPlayer` object, [as described in the Game Center Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW19).